# HTTP request / Service bus - application/x-www-form-urlencoded not supported error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I've got a really simple Logic app:

- HTTP request (works as end-point web hook for Slack)
- Send request from Slack (URI) to Service Bus queue

I haven't made any changes in Logic App but Send message action suddenly started reporting this error:

```
Decoding as string is not supported for content envelope of type 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.
```

Send message is defined like that:

```
"Send_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Label": "@{triggerBody()}"
                    },
...
```

I see only difference in request outputs:

BEFORE

```
Headers
{
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "User-Agent": "Slackbot,1.0,(+https://api.slack.com/robots)",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ...
}
Body
{
  "$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "$content": "dG9r..."
}
```

NOW

```
Headers
{
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "User-Agent": "Slackbot,1.0,(+https://api.slack.com/robots)",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   ...
}

Body
{
  "$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "$content": "dG9r...",
  "$formdata": [
    {
      "key": "token",
      "value": "..."
    },
    {
      "key": "team_id",
      "value": "..."
    },
    {
      "key": "trigger_word",
      "value": "!"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

$formdata is now a part of the output of Request as JSON array consisting of all query parameters.

Does anyone have any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any help to make it work again.

Edit: West Europe fixed and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the effort to have native support for x-www-form-urlencoded data in the runtime there was a bug that was recently released.  We are rolling back and patching now.  Can you send me an email so we can target your region for a fix, and share a workaround?  Apologies in advance - as a general rule we never want to ship anything that will break existing logic apps.  In this case adding some new metadata around form-data no longer allowed people to stringify x-www-form-urlencoded data (which is what you are doing here).

Comment: We were experiencing the same issue as J.F 2 days ago. Has this been resolved yet? We're in East US.

Comment: Yes it should have been rolled out globally Thursday and Friday of last week.